# Visa refusal-related tags

Tags: discussion

There are several tags relevant to visa refusals but (and apologies if I’ve missed it, or this question has been asked and answered before) there is no tag for ‘proof of ties’. Since this is one of the top reasons for a refusal, is it possible to create a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have enough rep to make a new tag, if I remember right.

Please try it, and make the relevant use pages as well.

If it does not work, ping me and I help you with it.

(Or ping someone else, if you like that better.

Comment: Thank you, I’ve created the new tag.